# Concatenate values in Excel for 200 rows

Tags: vba, excel, row, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 3 values in a row into one cell... 200 times. Copy and pasting the =Concatenate(D1,E1,F1) and  then changing the number 200 times would be fairly tedious. I have searched around for other people trying to do something like this and what they are asking isn't exactly what I need.

I tried using the ROW() function in the Concatenate() function like, =Concatenate(D..ROW(), E..ROW(), F..ROW()) . I know that the .. isn't the proper way to concatenate values in a function.

If their was something I could do like this with VBA or a macro that will easily concatenate the values into their respected cells.

I am trying to concatenate a street address, a city name and a postal code for 200 different people, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter:

**=Concatenate(D1,E1,F1)**

into a single cell.  Then copy this cell downward.  The references will automatically adjust.

Comment: Another way would be `=D1 & E1 & F1`